# SwiftでNavigationContorollerのタイトルを、ある程度以上の文字数の場合省略して表示したい

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

Navigation controllerに表示されてるタイトルが、
下の添付画像のようになってしまって困っています。

やりたいことは、　Navigation Controllerでデフォルトで表示される「< Back」を左端に表示したうえで、
その右横から、タイトルを表示させたいです。
しかし、しかし、今はそれができていません。
なにかよい方法はありますでしょうか?

WKWebViewのタイトルをKVOで監視して、
ページ遷移するたびにnaitaionitem.titleにページのタイトルをつっこみたいです。

navitionitem.titleに文字をつっこむときに、
都度都度文字数をカウントして、ある文字数以上であれば、
突っ込む前に突っ込む前に文字列の最後の方をカットする、
という実装も考えられのですが、
それはその都度やる必要があって面倒です。
一括で設定できるようなものがあればとぐぐったのですが見つからず困っています。

環境は、
El Capitan,Swift2,Xcode7.0.1です。
宜しく願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

```
let overCount: Int = // 文字数制限
var navigationTitle: String? {
    didSet {
        if var title = navigationTitle {
            if title.count <= overCount {
                navigationItem?.title = title
            } else {
                title = String(title.prefix(overCount))
                title += "…"
                navigationItem?.title = title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

でできるでしょうか。